# convert multi if-else statements to be more functional

Tags: java, functional-programming

How does one make an if else statement functional

```
boolean condition1;
boolean condition2;

final Object a = new Object();
final Object b = new Object();
final Object c = new Object();
final Object d = new Object();

if (condition1 && condition2) {
   return a;
}
else if (condition1 && !condition2) {
   return b;
}
else if (!condition1 && condition2) {
   return c;
}
else {
   return d;
}
```

I would like to know how can one refactor this type of conditional statements to be more functional, with no overhead in performance preferbly.

I was thinking of Mapping predicates to the object, would this be an approach?

Comment: What for? Java isn't a functional programming language, so you're most likely going to do something that's both less clear and less effective than what you can get with "standard" constructs. Functional code in Java has no *inherent* value, so what is it with people wanting to change their `for` loops into `forEach()` and so on? If you have a realistic example, post the code for that and we can suggest good solutions which may or may not be functional.

Comment: the goal of my question is mainly for understanding the principles of functional programming. Java i understand is not purely functional, but it is something i understand better

Comment: You've chosen a very poor example to understand Java's functional capabilities. As you see nobody has suggested any functional mechanisms in the answers, so if you try to force a functional solution, it will definitely be worse than alternatives.

Comment: `return condition1? condition2? a: b: condition2? c: d;`—not functional, but less redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two conditions there's nothing wrong with your if/then/else statements.  If you have more conditions, there's a way to "simplify" the code using a truth table.

```
public Object method()
{
    Object objects[] = { a, b, c, d }; // Assuming objects a, b, c and d exist...

    boolean condition1;
    boolean condition2;

    /* 
     * Truth Table
     * 
     *    condtion1  condition2   Object
     *      false      false        d
     *      false      true         c
     *      true       false        b
     *      true       true         a 
     */

    int selector = (condition1 ? 0 : 1) + (condition2 ? 0 : 2);

    return objects[selector];
}
```

Not sure if this is what you had in mind but it's a typical way to dispatch multiple conditions.  While at first glance it looks arcane, if you document the entire truth table for all conditions it can be very safe, since it forces you to consider ALL possible combinations.  This can really help when you have more than two conditions.

Comment: Let's not make the code even worse code and harder to debug. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with the if/else statements, but it is unnecessary to be instantiating 4 objects when only 25% of them will be used. In short, the if/else is the least of the problems here.

Comment: Interesting. I was wondering if a bitmask or something similar could be used, but this is quite clever. Is this approach described in some classic literature? I've never encountered it.

Comment: @Nick The example code also instantiates 4 objects, and object instantiation isn't the issue here. The answer also assumes that with more options the if/else can become even more unwieldy.

Comment: For two conditions you are correct. However, for a large number of conditions a truth-table is an accepted way to ensure that you have all the bases covered.

Comment: @Kayaman No points and prizes for being clever for the sake of it; this isn't a microcontroller where space is at a premium, and it sends the wrong message to an aspiring developer. Clarity and maintainability trumps obscurity. Let the compiler do the smart work.

Comment: @Nick I'm considering this with a wider aspect than just the code given in the question.

Comment: @Nick Nothing "clever" about this.  Expand the problem to 5 conditions, with 32 possible choices, and this method _forces_ you to consider every possibility.  A 32-entry if/then/else would be madness.  Truth-table-driven dispatch is a well-known and accepted technique.

Comment: @Jim agreed in principle on the truth table, however it can come at a big cost if all cells are populated before returning just one, and if the language doesn't support lazily evaluation on read or the table is not statically instantiated. Encouraging the OP not to be worried about 4 if's would be best advice here, and to assuage concerns of performance, to suggest not creating the results upfront. I think a more realistic and slightly larger example would lead to better answers. (to be fair Jim, you did acknowledge that the if's are fine.)

Comment: @Jim this is really interesting. Is the truth table lookup a common technique in functional programming?

Comment: This technique predates functional programming by decades.  You haven't really defined what you mean by "functional".

Answer (score 2):

I've added 2 more conditions to spice it up a bit. The if/else statements can get pretty in-depth, so you can use bit-wise to clarify things and merge the conditions. To me, this clarifies the code - cause it's one level deep, no matter how many conditions.

```
final int BIT_CONDITION_1 = 0x01;
final int BIT_CONDITION_2 = 0x02;
final int BIT_CONDITION_3 = 0x04;
final int BIT_CONDITION_4 = 0x08;


boolean condition1 = false;
boolean condition2 = false;
boolean condition3 = false;
boolean condition4 = false;

int mergedConditions = 0;
if (condition1)
    mergedConditions |= BIT_CONDITION_1;
if (condition2)
    mergedConditions |= BIT_CONDITION_2;
if (condition3)
    mergedConditions |= BIT_CONDITION_3;
if (condition4)
    mergedConditions |= BIT_CONDITION_4;
// continue as needed

// now you can check all conditions using the set bits.
switch(mergedConditions) {
    case 0:      // no bits set
        System.out.println("No bits set");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 2");
        break;
    // You can also clarify case statements by using constants
    case (BIT_CONDITION_1 | BIT_CONDITION_2):
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 1,2");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 3");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 1,3");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 2,3");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 1,2,3");
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 4");
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 1,4");
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 2,4");
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("Conditions set = 1,2,4");
        break;
    // etc ... Continue as needed
        }
```